# Phone numbers with regex (plus and spaces)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to catch all these numbers with a regex but I can't find a pattern.

Criteria for numbers:

1. Numbers can start with "00"
2. Numbers can start with "+"
3. Numbers can contain spaces between them.

it may be that before or after the phone number you have text.

Regex:

```
\b[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{2,6}[)]?[-\s\.]?[-\s\/\.0-9]{3,15}\b
```

Sample phone Numbers:

```
00491234567890
+491234567890

0123-4567890

0123 4567 789
0123 456 7890
0123 45 67 789

+490123 4567 789
+490123 456 7890
+49 123 45 67 789

123 4567 789
123 456 7890
123 45 67 789


+49 1234567890
+491234567890

0049 1234567890
0049 1234 567 890

(0049)1234567890
(+49)1234567890

(0049) 1234567890
(+49) 1234567890



text text (0049) 1234567890 text text
text text (+49) 1234567890 text text
```

Thanks.

Comment: And how long can a phone number be? And how long can a chunk be? And can area codes contain parenthesis? You aren't being very specific with your criteria here.

Comment: 11 digits (without +49 or 0049) , parenthesis maybe (+49) or (0049)

Comment: Does it have to be +49 or can it +22 or any toerh code. Also, does it have to contain 11 digits or is it a range. If it is a range, how wide is that range? All your sample phone numbers seem to contain either 9 or 10 digits, not 11.

Comment: yeah, can be another +49 or +22 or +34 , phone long is max 11 digits, +49 (+11 digits max) or 0049 (+11 digits max)

Comment: May be you better use a library like libphonenumber to parse. https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-libphonenumber

Comment: @toto why close ?

Comment: Because the answer is in the duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've written this regex to find phone numbers:

```
(\(?(0{1,2}|\+)\d{1,2}\)?)?([ -]*\d+)+
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a workaround on this. Let me know if this helps

```
^(\d|\+)[ \d-]+$
```

Comment: Any relevant code should be part of your question body, not on a separate site.

Comment: not found records on text before and/or after phone